# Adjusting iframe within table

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need advice on a simple exercise I am trying to do - I do not code to html UI usually.
The following code attempts to load 2 iframes within table cells:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id='outerdiv '>
    <iframe src="book.jsp" id='outiframe' scrolling=no >< /iframe>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id='summarydiv '>
    <iframe src="book-view.jsp" id='inneriframe' scrolling=no >< /iframe>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Obviously additional attributes have to be added to make the 2 iframes visible.
Currently,IE8 shows the iframes horizontally placed beside each other,with neither displaying in full.
Firefox only displays the top one.
What is the minimum  basic template needed here to make the 2 iframes adjust and be visible together - and resize well with the browser size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your closing iframe tags have a space in them

```
< /iframe>
```

Should be

```
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add extra div tags. give the id 'outerdiv' and 'summerydiv' to TD and set css style max-height and max-width.

It may able to hold your iFrames in position.